# Converting time in R to 24 hours

Tags: r

For simplicity, I have created the following code:

```
  some_data <- c(1, 12, 500, 1800, 9, 1230)
  df <- as.data.frame(some_data)
```

I would like to convert these times to a 24 hour scale. For example, the final output should be (1300, 1200, 1700, 1800, 900, 1230)

The main issues I have run into are that some of the data does not have the trailing 0 or 00, as with 1PM, but others do. I am not sure how I would add this to only the times that are missing it. These times are class times, so 12-7 is all PM, while 8-11 would be AM. Is there a more efficient way to do this, or do I have to manually change it because the times vary?

Comment: @MauritsEvers because times between 8-11 are AM and times 12-7 are PM. Since these are class times there is no class at 1am or 9pm

Comment: Thanks, should've read more carefully. It's clearly stated in your question. My bad. PS. Not my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be safe to assume all times less than 100 need to be multiplied by 100. After that, it's just a matter of correcting for times before 800:

```r
correct_times <- function(times) {
  times_hmm <- ifelse(times < 100,
                      times * 100,
                      times)

  ifelse(times_hmm < 800,
         times_hmm + 1200,
         times_hmm)
}
correct_times(c(1, 12, 500, 1800, 9, 1230))
#> [1] 1300 1200 1700 1800  900 1230
```

Answer (score 1):

It is work for your sample set

```
df$some_data=ifelse(df$some_data>100,df$some_data/100,df$some_data)
df$some_data=ifelse((df$some_data>=8&df$some_data<=11)|df$some_data>=12,df$some_data,df$some_data+12)

df$some_data*100
[1] 1300 1200 1700 1800  900 1230
```